# How to assign numpy.ndarray to temporary variable under nogil loop in cython?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython, gil

I'm trying to implement [implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit) recommender model and have issues with code run time calculating top 5 suggestions to ~11kk users over ~100k items.

I was able to partly solve the problem by numpy with some cython sparkles (in jupyter notebook). Lines with numpy sorting are still using single core:

```
%%cython -f
# cython: language_level=3
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: linetrace=True
# cython: binding=True
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

def test(users_items=np.random.rand(11402139//1000, 134751//100)
        , int N=5, show_progress=True, int num_threads=1):
    # Define User count and loops indexes
    cdef int users_c = users_items.shape[0], u, i
    # Predefine zero 2-D C-ordered array for recommendations
    cdef int[:,::1] users_recs = np.zeros((users_c, N), dtype=np.intc)
    for u in tqdm(range(users_c), total=users_c, disable=not show_progress):
        # numpy .dot multiplication using multiple cores
        scores = np.random.rand(134751//1000, 10).dot(np.random.rand(10))
        # numpy partial sort
        ids_partial = np.argpartition(scores, -N)[-N:]
        ids_top = ids_partial[np.argsort(scores[ids_partial])]
        # Fill predefined 2-D array
        for i in range(N):
            users_recs[u, i] = ids_top[i]
    return np.asarray(users_recs)
# Working example
tmp = test()
```

I profiled it - np.argpartition consumes 60% of function time and uses onde core. I'm trying to make it parallel, cause I have a server with 80 cores. So, I perform .dot operation on a subset of users (uses multiple cores) and plan to fill empty predefined array by numpy sorting results (which use single core) in parallel, but I'm stuck with error from question title:

```
%%cython -f
# cython: language_level=3
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: linetrace=True
# cython: binding=True
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from math import ceil
def test(int N=10, show_progress=True, int num_threads=1):
    # Define User and Item count and loops indexes
    cdef int users_c = 11402139//1000, items_c = 134751//100, u, i, u_b
    # Predefine zero 2-D C-ordered array for recommendations
    cdef int[:,::1] users_recs = np.zeros((users_c, N), dtype=np.intc)
    # Define memoryview var
    cdef float[:,::1] users_items_scores_mv
    progress = tqdm(total=users_c, disable=not show_progress)
    # For a batch of Users
    for u_b in range(5):
        # Use .dot operation which use multiple cores
        users_items_scores = np.random.rand(num_threads, 10).dot(np.random.rand(134751//100, 10).T)
        # Create memory view to 2-D array, which I'm trying to sort row wise
        users_items_scores_mv = users_items_scores
        # Here it starts, try to use numpy sorting in parallel
        for u in prange(num_threads, nogil=True, num_threads=num_threads):
            ids_partial = np.argpartition(users_items_scores_mv[u], items_c-N)[items_c-N:]
            ids_top = ids_partial[np.argsort(users_items_scores_mv[u][ids_partial])]
            # Fill predefined 2-D array
            for i in range(N):
                users_recs[u_b + u, i] = ids_top[i]
        progress.update(num_threads)
    progress.close()
    return np.asarray(users_recs)
```

and got this ([full error](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/H0bbitBaron/df91614c5b129e5dd92ae009fc30069d/raw/0e20079170f023b45bc4070b3b35fa932d35945c/error.txt)):

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        # Create memory view to 2-D array,
        # which I'm trying to sort row wise
        users_items_scores_mv = users_items_scores
        # Here it starts, try to use numpy sorting in parallel
        for u in prange(num_threads, nogil=True, num_threads=num_threads):
            ids_partial = np.argpartition(users_items_scores_mv[u], items_c-N)[items_c-N:]
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/datascc/enn/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_201b296cd5a34240b4c0c6ed3e58de7c.pyx:31:12: Assignment of Python object not allowed without gil
```

I read about memory views and malloc-ating but haven't found example applicable to my situation.

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve]. "Minimal" is a quite important part!

Comment: You're trying to call a Python function (np.argpartition) in a nogil block. Although the first message you get is about assigning variables I don't think this is the fundamental problem. I'm pretty sure this is never going to work.

Comment: @ead edited question to be more compact and reproducible.

Comment: @DavidW you are right, there is a list of [errors](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/H0bbitBaron/df91614c5b129e5dd92ae009fc30069d/raw/0e20079170f023b45bc4070b3b35fa932d35945c/error.txt), especially np.argpartition results in "Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil". I wonder is there alternative with no gil, may be in numpy C-API?

Comment: I think `np.argpartition` should be able to release the GIL internally, and thus if you put it inside a `with gil:` block then it should probably still manage to run multithreaded some of the of time. The trouble is that it doesn't really look like much of your code can run without the GIL, which may make it unsuitable for easy parallelization. You'd have to reimplement `argpartition` and `argsort` and possibly some indexing functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with custom C++ function, that fills numpy array in parallel with nogil via openmp. It required rewriting numpy's argpartition partial sorting with cython. Algorythm is like this (3-4 can be looped):

1. define empty array A[i,j] and [memory view](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) B_mv[i,k]; where "i" is batch size, "j" some columns and "k" number of desired items to be returned after sorting
2. create pointers on A&B's memory
3. run some calculations and fill A with data
4. iterate in parallel over i-s and fill B
5. transform result into readable form

Solution consists of:

topnc.h - header of custom function implementation:

```
/* "Copyright [2019] <Tych0n>"  [legal/copyright] */
#ifndef IMPLICIT_TOPNC_H_
#define IMPLICIT_TOPNC_H_

extern void fargsort_c(float A[], int n_row, int m_row, int m_cols, int ktop, int B[]);

#endif  // IMPLICIT_TOPNC_H_
```

topnc.cpp - body of the function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include "topnc.h"

struct target {int index; float value;};
bool targets_compare(target t_i, target t_j) { return (t_i.value > t_j.value); }

void fargsort_c ( float A[], int n_row, int m_row, int m_cols, int ktop, int B[] ) {
    std::vector<target> targets;
    for ( int j = 0; j < m_cols; j++ ) {
        target c;
        c.index = j;
        c.value = A[(n_row*m_cols) + j];
        targets.push_back(c);
    }
    std::partial_sort( targets.begin(), targets.begin() + ktop, targets.end(), targets_compare );
    std::sort( targets.begin(), targets.begin() + ktop, targets_compare );
    for ( int j = 0; j < ktop; j++ ) {
        B[(m_row*ktop) + j] = targets[j].index;
    }
}
```

ctools.pyx - example usage

```
# distutils: language = c++
# cython: language_level=3
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: nonecheck=False
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "topnc.h":
    cdef void fargsort_c ( float A[], int n_row, int m_row, int m_cols, int ktop, int B[] ) nogil

A = np.zeros((1000, 100), dtype=np.float32)
A[:] = np.random.rand(1000, 100).astype(np.float32)
cdef:
    float[:,::1] A_mv = A
    float* A_mv_p = &A_mv[0,0]
    int[:,::1] B_mv = np.zeros((1000, 5), dtype=np.intc)
    int* B_mv_p = &B_mv[0,0]
    int i
for i in prange(1000, nogil=True, num_threads=10, schedule='dynamic'):
    fargsort_c(A_mv_p, i, i, 100, 5, B_mv_p)
B = np.asarray(B_mv)
```

compile.py - compile file; run it by command "python compile.py build_ext --inplace -f" in terminal (this will result in file ctools.cpython-*.so, which you then use for import):

```
from os import path
import numpy
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_utils = Extension(
    'ctools'
    , sources=['ctools.pyx', 'topnc.cpp']
    , include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    , extra_compile_args=['-std=c++0x', '-Os', '-fopenmp']
    , extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
    , language='c++'
)

setup(
    name='ctools',
    setup_requires=[
        'setuptools>=18.0'
        , 'cython'
        , 'numpy'
    ]
    , cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext}
    , ext_modules=cythonize([ext_utils]),
)
```

It was used for [adding](https://github.com/benfred/implicit/pull/179) "recommend all" functionality into [implicit](https://implicit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ALS model.